# unable to get access_token from facebook. it returns code parameter

Tags: facebook, video, upload, facebook-php-sdk

i am using php sdk. here is my php code

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123456',
  'secret' => '123456abcdef',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//echo "-----".$user;

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }  

    //print_r($user_profile);
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //echo $token;
    // store token

    if ($user_profile['id'] && $token) {
    $useradd = mysql_query("insert into fbdata (id,name,token) values ('".$user_profile['id']."','".$user_profile['name']."','".$token."')");
    if ($uyeekle)
    echo "Data added";
    }
}


if (!$user) {
    $args['scope'] = 'offline_access,read_stream,publish_stream';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>">Facebook Login</a>
<?php } ?>
```

facebook redirect to my website with code parameter, not access token. and it s not looking like access token format. there is no | char. But i will try to upload a video with this code it works.

```
require 'src/facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123456',
  'secret' => '123456abcdef',
));
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title=abc&description=desc&access_token=ABAD........AZDZD";


$attachment = array(
'description' => 'desc',
'title' => 'abc'
);


$attachment["file"] = '@' . realpath("123.mp4");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

this code returns video id. then i want to get video info from that addresss
https://graph.facebook.com/123456?access_token=ABAD........AZDZD

but its always saying false. where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting with a code instead of an access token is expected behavior, confirmed by the [Facebook Authentication docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). When using server-side auth (PHP SDK), Facebook will redirect to http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER. You then have to resolve this code into an access token yourself (which you can do just by calling `$facebook->getAccessToken()`). And as you say, you can then use this access token (**not** the code from the redirect) to make API calls.

If you're using the Facebook PHP SDK, you should just use that to make those API calls. I'm not sure about the specifics for uploading videos, but it should look something like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '123456',
    'secret' => '123456abcdef',
    'fileUpload' => true,
));

$attachment = array(
    'description' => 'desc',
    'title'       => 'abc',
    'file'        => '@' . realpath("123.mp4");
);

$result = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', $attachment);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: first of all thx for reply.
i am uploading with succesfully with "code". there is no problem. i want to get video info but i cannot do that.

Comment: I see. I was confused because that is a different question than the one in the title.